# Serialize a pyspark dataframe using schema in glue schema registry and send it to kafka topic

Tags: pyspark, serialization, apache-kafka, jsonschema, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to send the output of a dataframe as serialized objects to Kafka topic. This serialisation should happen with the json schema we have pulled from Glue schema registry. Right now i can not think of a way to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly helpful. Thanks